# FastAPI call file from same level, but in different directory

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I'm having trouble importing my file from another directory (same level just different directory).

My models directory is at ./models containing my personModel.py file that has my BaseModel definition

personModel.py

```
class Person(BaseModel):
  name: str
  age: int
```

I want to call it to my ./routes containing my person.py file. I did this and did not work since it's not from the same directory

Person.py

```
from personModel import Person
```

How should I do this? Thank you

Edit (Tree structure):

```
api
└── model
    └── personModel.py
└── routes
    └── Person.py
```

so, the two pathways are project/backend/api/model/personModel.py and project/backend/api/routes/Person.py

Comment: Try importing it using `from models.personModel import Person`, you need to add module namespace before accessing the file.

Comment: I have edited my tree hopefully that can be clearer?

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and got `ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "personModel"`

Comment: Tnx for the tree, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66393809/8488594

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your updated tree structure You need to add `__init__.py` files to both `model` and `routes` directory, so python treats them like python modules.
And then the import I mentioned in the comment would work properly:

```
api
└── __init__.py
└── model
    └── __init__.py
    └── personModel.py
└── routes
    └── __init__.py
    └── Person.py
```

```py
from model.personModel import Person
```

Comment: I'm facing this error now: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'`

Comment: from model.personModel, I made the same typo in my answer originally too

Comment: very weird, I changed it and I still get the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'`

Comment: @unsaturatedgoods Add one `__init__.py` to the `api` folder and try againg

Answer (score -1):

One rule I typically try to follow is to always declare the path starting from the root directory (ie. wherever you create the FastAPI "app" object). It really helps keep me organized and removes the confusion of relative imports. Wherever you have your **main.py** file should be your "root". It alse helps if you were to use pytest or async-pytest, as I've had trouble with that in the past.

```py
from api.model.personModel import Person
```

that *should* do it for you, given there isn't some other weird stuff going on. Keep in mind the file import will be relative to whatever file is the root of the application (again, whatever file has your "app" creation).

Comment: There are missing `__init__.py` files in modules, Adding `api` prefix would only pollute the import statements.

Comment: This did not work, I did have the `__init.py__` files prior, so I'm confused as to why it is not working.

Comment: I was assuming you already had those. Do you have an `__init__.py` in ./api as well?

Comment: I do, I'm faced with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'` this now (btw I'm doing `from model.personModel import Person`)